# What is the correct option ? Its C mentioned in the source I referred. But I feel its d

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors, malloc, runtime-error

Consider the following three C functions:

[P1]

```
int *g(void) {
    int x = 10;
    return (&x);
}
```

[P2]

```
int *g(void) {
    int *px;
    *px = 10;
    return px;
}
```

[P3]

```
int *g(void) {
    int *px;
    px = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *px = 10;
    return px;
}
```

Which of the above three functions are likely to cause problems with pointers?

a. Only P3
b. Only P1 and P3
c. Only P1 and P2
d. P1, P2 and P3

I feel it should be **d** because if heap is full, `malloc` will return a null pointer and P3 can even fail. But then wherever I see on the Internet, everywhere its mentioned option **c**. I'd like to hear all of your opinions on this !

Comment: The first two have undefined behavior.  The first returns a pointer to an object that has gone out of scope.  The second is storing through an undefined pointer value, and returning an undefined pointer value.  The third looks safe (although you should always check the return value from `malloc` since it could be `NULL`).

Comment: P1 allocates x on the stack and then returns the address of x. Upon completion of P1 x is popped off the stack and any reference to x is invalid.

P2 creates an uninitialized pointer to an int on the stack then assigns the address 10 to px. The value returned will be whatever is at address 10. It will not have any relationship with the integer 10.

P3 creates an int pointer px then dynamically allocates an int to px. Finally it sets the allocated int to 10. P3 is correct if you want to pass the int 10 out of the function.

Comment: Yes, you are technically correct. In P3 the line `*px = 10;` should be preceded by `if (px != NULL)`. Returning a `NULL` pointer from the function is ok, let the caller deal with it. But using a `NULL` pointer is not ok.

Answer (score 3):

Given that the question asks which is **likely** to cause problems, the correct answer would be c) P1 and P2.

P1 returns the address of a local variable.  If that address is dereferenced (or even read) it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

P2 dereferences an uninitialized pointer, which again is undefined behavior.

P3 allocates memory with `malloc`, stores a value in that memory location, and returns the pointer to the allocated memory.  While it's true that this could cause a problem if `malloc` failed, it's less likely to be a problem than outright undefined behavior.